# Has there ever been any episode that didn't show a stargate in use?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis, stargate-universe

I've been watching old SG-1 episodes lately and a question came to me. Has there been any episode (SG-1, ATL, SGU) where it **didn't** show the stargate being used?

Being used for the purposes of this question includes the "whoosh", someone/something entering/exiting through shimmering pool of "water", or simply using it as a walkie-talkie to communicate with someone off-world.

Comment: The technical term is 'kawhoosh'.

Comment: I started writing an answer, but the actual answer is "[Yes, bloody loads](http://forum.gateworld.net/archive/index.php/t-70737.html)". At this point I'm going to give up. If someone wants to do a better job, good luck to them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There have been a number of episodes in Stargate SG1, Atlantis and Universe where there is zero use of the gate, save for the opening credits.

Some examples are below;

### SG1

[Nightwalkers](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s6/605.shtml)
[Prometheus](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Prometheus)
[The Curse](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Curse)
[Wormhole X-Treme!](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Wormhole_X-Treme!_(episode))

### Stargate Atlantis

[The Defiant One](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/The_Defiant_One)
[The Hot Zone](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Hot_Zone)
[McKay and Mrs Miller](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/McKay_and_Mrs._Miller)

### Stargate: Universe

[Light](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Light)

Comment: If we're being picky, SG-1's [Unnatural Selection](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Unnatural_Selection) shows an active Stargate, but only in O'Neil's mind. No "real" Stargate was activated.

Comment: @Thunderforge - This isn't an exhaustive list. I just picked an example  (or four) from each series.